# Python - reading all files in a directory and then returning the max value based on some function

Tags: python, for-loop, text, directory

I'm trying to create a function that opens and reads every file in a directory and then returns the file with the highest value based on some function. In this case, I'm using a function called sentiment analysis from the Textblob library to evaluate how optimistic or negative each text file is. So the end goal is to find the most optimistic .txt file in the directory.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import sys
import glob

def optimistic():
    path = 'Download/textfiles/*.txt'   
    files = glob.glob(path) 
    max_sent = 0
    for name in files: 
         with open(name) as f:
            sys.stdout.write(f.read())
            if TextBlob(f).sentiment > max_sent:
               max_sent = TextBlob(f).sentiment    
         return name
```

I'm a little uncertain about wether I'm reading each file in the directory properly and wether I'm comparing each file to all others correctly in order to return the max. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For example, whenever I try to print 'files' I just get [ ]. I'm also not sure if I should be returning name. I can skip over to Code Review, but any help is also appreciated.

Comment: if `files == []`, it just means that there is no file matching your pattern. Be sure your path is correct.

Comment: @newrecruit21 - not sure why koukouviou recommended Code Review. Your code cannot possibly be working because it only scans the first file (`return name`)

Comment: I thought so. How about what Julien Spronck wrote below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good except for the `return` value. In your code, it will always return the first name in `files` and not iterate through them. Maybe, you want to try this instead. I just made a minimal change in your code, in which I assign a `max_name` variable every time I find a new maximum and then return that value.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import sys
import glob

def optimistic():
    path = 'Download/textfiles/*.txt'   
    files = glob.glob(path) 
    max_sent = 0
    max_name = ''
    for name in files: 
         with open(name, 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()
            sentiment = TextBlob(text).sentiment
            if sentiment > max_sent:
                max_sent = sentiment
                max_name = name   
    return max_name
```

Note that I also open the files in read-only mode since you do not write to them: `open(name, 'r')`. Additionally, since TextBlob needs a string as input, I first converted your file into a string.

Comment: This is great, thanks. However, the only problem now is that it says that f isn't a string. Textblob only works on strings. (I fixed the path btw).

Comment: i don't know TextBlob but I'll make an edit if it needs strings.

Comment: @newrecruit21... I just made an edit ... hope it works for you.

Comment: That would be awesome.

Comment: @newrecruit21You're welcome :-) I just made a tiny change to get the file content `text = f.read()` instead of `text = '\n'.join(f.readlines())`. should be simpler and better.